# CreateProcess to execute Windows command

Tags: windows, winapi, cmd, createprocess

I am trying to execute a dos command using CreateProcess function :

```
 LPWSTR cmd=(LPWSTR)QString("C:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe  subst " + DLetter+"  \""+mountPath+"\"").utf16();



        STARTUPINFO si;
        PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
        ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
        si.cb = sizeof(si);
        ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );

        if ( CreateProcessW(0,     // Application name
                           cmd,                 // Application arguments
                           NULL,
                           NULL,
                           TRUE,
                           0,
                           NULL,
                           L"C:\\windows\\system32",          // Working directory
                           &si,
                           &pi) == TRUE)
        { ...
```

it give  as last error 3 = ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND, when I separate the application path `"C:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe"` from the command it shows the console without executing my subst command.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You could call `DefineDosDevice()` which (non-persistently) does the same thing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to include either /C or /K in the options to `cmd.exe`.

```
/C      Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates
/K      Carries out the command specified by string but remains
```

Without one these options, the `subst` command that you pass is simply ignored.

Having said that, `subst`, at least on my Windows 7 box, is not implemented inside `cmd.exe`. It is a separate executable. So you can invoke it directly and bypass `cmd.exe` completely.

Regarding your call to `CreateProcess` I have the following comments:

1. Don't include the path `C:\\windows\\system32`. Just invoke `subst.exe` and let the system locate the executable using the standard search path.
2. Pass `FALSE` for `bInheritHandles`. You aren't passing any handles to the new process and so you don't need the new process to inherit your handles.
3. Pass `NULL` as the working directory. There's just no need to specify it here.

Comment: thank you David it works I invoked subst.exe with my arguments but I didn't find the mounted drive under Computer with C:/ and D:/ , did subst run with an admin rights so that's why I didn't find my new drive ?(I am a simple user)

Comment: I'm not sure. I think that's a different question.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: even better, dont use the `subst` executable to manipulate drive mappings. Use Win32 API functions directly, such as `DosDefineDevice()`, `WNetAddConnection...()`, `WNetCancelConnection...()`, etc.

Comment: Er yes, that's a much better idea, @Remy

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
"C:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe /c subst " + DLetter+"  \""+mountPath+"\""
```

instead. CMD won't accept arguments without either `/c` or `/k`, and unless you want to see the output in the console window, just use `/c`.

Comment: Not me - but why two instances of cmd?  Also the second one is missing the /c.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Thanks, it was a typo when I was answering it.